# Seemingly simple optimization problem is slow

Tags: plotting, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to generate a demand curve numerically, given a utility function.  The function for the demand is defined like so:

```
Demand[UF_, x_, m_, w_, p_] := NArgMax[{UF, {x >= 0, m >= 0, p x + m <= w}}, {x, m}][[1]]
```

Where `UF` is the utility, `x` is consumption of a good, `w` is consumption of everything else in dollars, `p` is the price of the good in dollars and `w` is the budget.  The constraints say that consumption must be non-negative and that the budget must not be exceeded.

Now I'm trying to plot the demand curve for an innocent looking utility function:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Demand[5 Sqrt[x] + m, x, m, w, p], {p, 1, 10}], {w, 1, 100}]
```

This is very slow.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because numerical optimization is a slow thing. You can interpolate the `Demand` function for your particular utility to speed the manipulation up:

```
Clear[Demand];
Demand[uf_, w_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[
  {uf[x, m], {x >= 0, m >= 0, p x + m <= w}}, {x, m}][[1]]
g = FunctionInterpolation[
  Demand[5 Sqrt[#1] + #2 &, w, p],
  {w, 1, 100}, {p, 1, 10}]
Manipulate[Plot[g[w, p], {p, 1, 10}], {w, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: The documentation on `FunctionInterpolation` is a bit sparse but checking `Options[FunctionInterpolation]` you see it takes some options: `{InterpolationOrder -> 3, InterpolationPrecision -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, InterpolationPoints -> 11, MaxRecursion -> 6}` that are all described elsewhere in the the documentation